# Formatar JSON no cakephp

Tags: cakephp, json

Estou gerando um jSon a partir de um *find* no CakePhp.

### Controller:

```
    public function listar() {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->set('resultados', $this->Sala->listarSala());
    }
```

### Model:

```
    public function listarSala() {
    $options = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Sala.id', 'Sala.nome', 'Sala.data', 'Sala.inicio', 'Sala.fim'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Sala.data >= curdate()',
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Sala.data ASC',
            'Sala.inicio ASC'
        ),
        'limit' => 50
    );
    return $this->find('all', $options);
}
```

### View:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($resultados);
```

Porém quando visualizo a resposta, obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
[
{"Sala":{"id":"47","nome":"Grupo","data":"15\/05\/2014","inicio":"09:30:00","fim":"11:00:00"}},
{"Sala":{"id":"48","nome":"Grupo","data":"29\/05\/2014","inicio":"09:30:00","fim":"11:00:00"}},
{"Sala":{"id":"49","nome":"Grupo","data":"12\/06\/2014","inicio":"09:30:00","fim":"11:00:00"}}
]
```

Observei que ele cria um objeto sala(model) e dentro dele as propriedades buscadas no MySql.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como eu poderia fazer para o CakePhp retornar este resultado sem o objeto sala, com a notação normal do jSon, ou seria assim mesmo? Qual seria a forma correta?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa formatar o *array* de retorno do CakePhp para que o jSon seja apresentado da forma correta.

No seu caso você precisa descer um nível no *array*.

Deixe sua view da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
foreach ($resultados as $sala) {
    $salas[] = $sala["Sala"];
}
echo json_encode($salas);
```

Comment: Desta forma funcionou:
`<?php
foreach ($resultados as $sala) {
    $salas[] = $sala["Sala"];
}
echo json_encode($salas);`

Comment: Mas não era exatamente isso que eu pretendia, queria um modo que este resultado já viesse assim do cake.

Comment: "Sala" no cake representa o model que você está utilizando e o normal é que ele sempre te diga isso, faz parte das convenções do framework. Isso ajuda na manutenção do código futuramente

Answer (score 0):

O Cake informa que pode retornar um Response dessa forma é só passar o objeto ou a lista de objetos dentro do exemplo abaixo

```
public function listar() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    //$this->set('resultados', $this->Sala->listarSala());
    $salas = $this->Sala->listarSala();
    $response = $this->response->withType('application/json')
        ->withStringBody(json_encode(['salas' => $salas]));   
    return $response;     
}
```